# API does not return all activities

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to use pagination to retrieve all the video uploading activities in a YouTube channel:

```py
import googleapiclient.discovery

api_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

def main():
    api_service_name = "youtube"
    api_version = "v3"
    
    youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, developerKey=api_key)

    next_page_token = 0
    while next_page_token is not None:
        request = youtube.activities().list(
            part="snippet,contentDetails",
            channelId="UCG-KntY7aVnIGXYEBQvmBAQ",
            maxResults=50,
            pageToken = None if next_page_token == 0 else next_page_token
        )

        response = request.execute()
        
        for item in response['items']:
            try:
                id = item['contentDetails']['playlistItem']['resourceId']['videoId']
                type = 'watched'
            except:
                id = item['contentDetails']['upload']['videoId']
                type = 'upload'

            if type == 'upload':
                print(type, id, item['snippet']['title'])
        
        next_page_token = response.get('nextPageToken')
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

For some reason, I get only 29 video uploads for a channel that has many more uploads than that.

Why is this happening?

**EDIT** I printed the dates of watching activities for my channel, i.e. `item['snippet']['publishedAt']` and saw something very strange. Namely, activities of 2023 are followed by activities in 2020, which are followed by activities in 2016. It's like it took some recent activities, some activities a few years ago and some of the earliest ones. Somehow it decided to show only 29 activities in total, while it shows 79 for the channel of Thomas Frank (it's actually interesting why I am allowed to know which videos he watched)

Comment: You'll have to ask YouTube.  Perhaps they have an age limit or a content limit.  I know they have strongly limited unpaid API accounts.

Comment: @TimRoberts My YouTube account is Premium. Is there a paid YouTube API?

Comment: @TimRoberts Please see the edit in the question.

Comment: You only register it as an upload if the first fetch fails.  Are you absolutely certain that your upload activities will not pass the first fetch?  Perhaps you should look for `'upload'` FIRST, if that's your primary interest.

Comment: @TimRoberts This is a minor issue. The major one is that YouTube chooses which activities to return using rules that do not seem predictable, which makes it impossible to use several requests to obtain all the activities.